# What kind of progression is this?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions

Sometimes I listen to some songs and try to get the underlying features of it, and this time I've hit a bump.... I have no idea what is the progression on the following song:

[image]

It's TheFatRat and AleXa's "Rule the World" chorus part. If I transcribed it correctly, that's the song. In case the image doesn't show, the chords are Bb-F-G-C, on an F Major scale. So, from the little I know on music theory, this song's progression should be IV-I-II-V, right?

However, I haven't found this specific progression in my researches. Am I understanding this progression incorrectly, or does this progression actually exists? If it does, what's its name?

Comment: The song is in F and needs b-flat as signature. That’s why Aaron’s analysis is correct.



Btw.:

Your rhythmic notation lacks of transparency. Usually this rhythm should be notated by 2 tied 16th on the syncopation: *gate, top, space, up.*

Comment: I used a random notation online solution just to describe what I was thinking, I didn't aim for precise notation, at that moment. As for the signature, I had forgotten, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing your transcription is correct, then yes, the progression is IV-I-II-V. However, since the II chord has a raised third (B-natural rather than B-flat), it would be better written as IV-I-V/V-V. V/V (read: five of five) means that chord functions as a dominant chord relative to the following C chord. This is called a "[secondary dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_chord)".

The progression itself doesn't have a name, but an ending on a dominant chord is called a "[half cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence#Half_cadence)".

Comment: Or, an imperfect cadence, to the right of the pond.

Comment: @ASousa Good point. I've added a couple of links to Wikipedia definitions.